# Memory leak in obj-c/c++ code

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

I'm using instruments and I have a lot of memory being leaked by this method. It is used everywhere in my app, and when I built it, I used some c++ (i think).

Please let me know where the leak is happening if possible?

Instruments just says Malloc 16 bytes and has about 60 MB worth of these guys...

```
/*
 Parses a dicionary into an object
 */
+(id)makeObject:(id)object fromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict{

    @autoreleasepool {
        NSArray *keys = @[@"@\"NSMutableArray\""];

        //Init result
        id result = object;

        //Iterate every key
        for (id key in [dict allKeys]) {

            //Convert key to const char
            const char * c = [key cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

            //Use c to see if the class has this property
            if (class_getProperty([object class], c)) {

                //get the property
                objc_property_t property = class_getProperty([result class], c);

                //Get the property name and type
                const char *name = property_getName(property);
                const char *type = property_copyAttributeValue(property, "T");

                //Cast const char to string
                NSString *pNameString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",name];
                NSString *typeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",type];

                //Add relationships
                if ([keys containsObject:typeString]) {

                    //Get array of objects
                    NSArray *relationship = [dict objectForKey:pNameString];

                    NSMutableArray *allSubObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                    //Parse each individual object
                    for (NSDictionary *relationshipObj in relationship) {

                        //Create class from relationship
                        Class class = NSClassFromString(pNameString);

                        //Create object
                        id sub = [self makeObject:[[class alloc]init] fromDictionary:relationshipObj];

                        [allSubObjects addObject:sub];
                    }

                    [result setValue:allSubObjects forKey:pNameString];
                }else{
                    //If so set the property for the key
                    [result setValue:[dict objectForKey:key] forKey:key];
                }

            }else{
                //NSLog(@"%@ did not respond to : %@", result, key);
            }


        }

        //Return result
        return result;
    }

}
```

EDIT:

Instruments shows these two items most likely the culprits. What's the best way to fix this?

```
//Cast const char to string
                    NSString *pNameString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",name];
                    NSString *typeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",type];
```

Comment: Declare this allocation out of the for loop(Master) NSMutableArray *allSubObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; and check once.

Comment: try to change  NSMutableArray *allSubObjects = [NSMutableArray array]; in order to create autoreleased instance

Comment: Just tried it... Leaks are still there

Comment: What line did instruments say the leak was on? If you select one of the leaks, open up the stack trace and double-click on the function name, it will take you to the line of code where the leak occurred.

Comment: It says right here:                 NSString *typeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",type];

Comment: Terrible code.  Really needs a tidy up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `[NSString cStringUsingEncoding]`

This allocate some memory internally which will not freed until the NSString object is deallocated. I don't know exactly but could it be possible repeatedly sending cStringUsingEncoding incur unused memory building up?

2) `property_copyAttributeValue`

Documentation says,

> Return Value A C array of pointers of type objc_property_t describing
>   the properties declared by proto. Any properties declared by other
>   protocols adopted by this protocol are not included. The array
>   contains *outCount pointers followed by a NULL terminator. You must
>   free the array with free().

You need to free `const char *type`.

3) `NSMutableArray *allSubObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]`

It should be `NSMutableArray *allSubObjects = [NSMutableArray array]`.

4) Object creation

```
Class class = NSClassFromString(pNameString);    
//Create object
id sub = [self makeObject:[[class alloc]init] fromDictionary:relationshipObj];
```

I'd put this code block in its own autorelease pool.
`[class alloc]init]` is also suspicious.